# Aimeos Laravel - Add Custom Field in Product Add Form

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

I am new to Aimeos, so need help! I am building an e-Commerce website in Laravel with the help of Aimeos Laravel Package.

I have created my own Aimeos extension. Now Aimeos Product form has "SKU" field. I want to add another field named "Old SKU." So, I overwrite the existing template for form section (Basic) and added the new field. This is the directory structure "./ext/myextension/admin/jqadm/templates/product" for changing the template of Product form.

I also extended "mshop_product" with the help of this document: [Aimeos - Schema update](https://aimeos.org/docs/Developers/Library/Setup_tasks/Schema_update) and added a field in the table, field name "oldcode."

But the issue I am facing is that I am unable to save this value in table.

I followed this link: [Aimeos - Extend managers items](https://aimeos.org/docs/Developers/Library/Extend_managers_items) but it is very confusing.

I have created an Item Class

```
namespace Aimeos\MAdmin\Product\Item;

class Myproject extends Standard
{
        private $myvalues;

        public function __construct( array $values, ... )
        {
                parent::__construct( $values, ... )
                $this->myvalues = $values;
        }

        public function getMyId()
        {
                if( isset( $this->myvalues['myid'] ) ) {
                        return (string) $this->myvalues['myid'];
                }
                return '';
        }

        public function setMyId( $val )
        {
                if( (string) $val !== $this->getMyId() )
                {
                        $this->values['myid'] = (string) $myid;
                        $this->setModified();
                }
                return $this;
        }

        public function fromArray( array $list )
        {
                $unknown = [];
                $list = parent::fromArray( $list );

                foreach( $list as $key => $value )
                {
                        switch( $key )
                        {
                                case 'myid': $this->setMyId( $value ); break;
                                default: $unknown[$key] = $value;
                        }
                }

                return $unknown;
        }

        public function toArray( $private = false )
        {
                $list = parent::toArray( $private );

                if( $private === true ) {
                        $list['myid'] = $this->getMyId();
                }

                return $list;
        }
}
```

And I have created Manager Class:

```
namespace Aimeos\MAdmin\Product\Manager;

class Myproject extends Standard
{
        private $searchConfig = array(
                'product.oldcode'=> array(
                        'code'=>'product.oldcode',
                        'internalcode'=>'mpro."oldcode"',
                        'label'=>'Product oldcode',
                        'type'=> 'string', // integer, float, etc.
                        'internaltype'=> \Aimeos\MW\DB\Statement\Base::PARAM_STR, // _INT, _FLOAT, etc.
                ),
        );

        public function saveItem( \Aimeos\MShop\Common\Item\Iface $item, $fetch = true )
        {
                // a modified copy of the code from the parent class
                // extended by a bind() call and updated bind positions (first parameter)
        }

        public function getSearchAttributes( $withsub = true )
        {
                $list = parent::getSearchAttributes( $withsub );
                foreach( $this->searchConfig as $key => $fields ) {
                        $list[$key] = new \Aimeos\MW\Criteria\Attribute\Standard( $fields );
                }
                return $list;
        }

        protected function createItemBase( array $values = [] /* , ... */ )
        {
                return new \Aimeos\MShop\Product\Item\Myproject( $values /* , ... */ );
        }
}
```

And I have also added a config file:

```
return [
    'product' => [
        'manager' => [
            'name' => 'Myproject'
        ],
    ],
];
```

But value is not being saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after struggling with many things I have sorted out the solution. There were many mistakes in my code. The working version of my code can be found [here](https://aimeos.org/help/post5940.html#p5940)